# How to close app/activity or code menu item via intent/pendingIntent in Chrome Custom Tabs

Tags: android, android-intent, menuitem, android-pendingintent, chrome-custom-tabs

I'm trying to understand how Chrome Custom Tabs work. Following the guidelines, adding a custom item to a menu is done using a pendingIntent, such as:

```
Intent intent =  new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://google.com"));
PendingIntent pendingIntent =  PendingIntent
        .getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
customTabsIntent = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder()
        .addMenuItem("Visit Google Website", pendingIntent)
        .build();
```

I know how to use pendingIntent to direct to a website or to create a 'share' action. The question is would it be possible to do more complex tasks from adding a 'Close' menu item to close the activity or to exit app; or to 'connect' that menu item to a method, so when the user clicks on it the code from the method would process. I guess the second if possible would than make an easy solution for the first.

I tried to search for the answers, but if I search how to close or end activity or app (or similar) using intent or pendingIntent, I get something with use of 'finish();' or 'startActivity(intent);' or similar, which I cannot apply here since I don't know how or from where to call it. I tried just reading about the use of intent and pendingIntent, but I cannot figure out how to, let's say close activity or process without being able to call a method.

I would appreciate any help, even some links to resources or pointers to what I would need to read/learn next to be able to understand this.

Comment: Could explain better the behaviour you are trying to achieve? It seems that you want to have a button in CCT that will cause the Activity that invoked Custom Tabs to be finished, is that right?

Comment: @andreban: If there is no Chrome on the device, the app will open the link in the user's default browser. In that case if you open the 'task manager' to see 'running apps' on the device you would see both the App and the user browser running. If Chrome version 45 or above is installed on the device and selected as the default browser, than CCT will open and if you open the 'task manager' to see 'running apps' you would see only the App running (like CCT opens within - Chrome browser is not launched).

Comment: @andreban: So yes, I am trying to add, well not necessarily a button, but a custom menu item to CCT menu, to close the 'whole thing', with a presumption that when I close the app the CCT would close as well. Though I think it would be the same if you wanted to do it via a custom action button as, as far as I am aware, both are controlled by intent/pendIntent, such as described in my example above.

Comment: So, you want to add a menu item that "Exits" the app? (eg: closes the Custom Tab and the caller Activity).  If that's the case, Android doesn't really have the concept of exiting an Application. I'd recommend reading the Activity Lifecycle docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html. As for Custom Tab, it's not possible to close the Custom Tab from the BroadcastReceiver, as it's also not usually possible to do with other Activities. You could use finish() on the caller Activity when it's is restarted after Custom Tabs is closed.

Comment: @andreban: I beg to differ; see my solution using BroadcastReceiver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution is using BrodcastReceiver:

In your activity (MainActivity in this case) from which you are starting Chrome Custom Tabs (CCT), create a static field to identify if the activity was created from the Broadcastreceiver, and a setter so we can set it from the Broadcastreceiver:

```
    // For determining if Activity was started from BroadcastReceiver
    private static boolean fromBroadcastReceiver = false;

    public static void setFromBroadcastReceiver(boolean bool) {
        fromBroadcastReceiver = bool;
    }
```

Create a public class for BroadcastReceiver. Overriding the onReceive method, create an instance of the MainActivity and set `fromBroadcastReceiver` to true. Then create an intent with that activity and another intent for restarting using first intent. Close CCT and restart the activity using latter intent:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.content.IntentCompat;

public class CctBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        // Create an instance of MainActivity and set fromBroadcastReceiver flag to true.
        MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();
        mainActivity.setFromBroadcastReceiver(true);

        // Create an intent with that activity and another intent for restarting using first intent.
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, mainActivity.getClass());
        ComponentName compName = intent.getComponent();
        Intent mainIntent = IntentCompat.makeRestartActivityTask(compName);

        // Restart the activity using later intent (also close CCT)
        mainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        mainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
        context.startActivity(mainIntent);

    } // End onReceive.

} // End BroadcastReceiver class.
```

Don't forget to register your receiver in the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
...
        </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name=".cctBroadcastReceiver"
        android:enabled="true">
    </receiver>

</application>
```

Now, inside `onCreate` of the MainActivity check if it was created from the BroadcastReceiver, and if so reset the 'flag' and `finish()` the activity:

```
        // Check if activity was created from the BroadcastReceiver, and if so reset the 'flag' and finish() the activity.
        if (fromBroadcastReceiver) {
            setFromBroadcastReceiver(false);
            finish();
            return;
        }
```

Don't forget to use your BroadcastReceiver class for creating intent and pendingIntent for CCT:

```
     Intent broadcastIntent =  new Intent(this, CctBroadcastReceiver.class);
     PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, broadcastIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

And you're done. Basically the code inside the BroadcastReceiver closes the CCT (similar as if you clicked on the CCT default close button). Adding the 'flag' and the code inside the MainActivity further closes the MainActivity.

Comment: What is `browserActivity`?

Comment: @qbix: Sorry, it should be mainActivity. I changed it. Thanks.